# How to fetch the list of all the localized and locally created Components in a Folder for a particular Publication using core service?

Tags: core-service, 2011-sp1

How to fetch the list of all the localized and locally created Components in a Folder for a particular Publication using core service?

Currently I am first fetching all the Components using the following code.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<XNode> GetFolderItems(string folderUri, ItemType itemType)
{
    OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
    IEnumerable<XNode> folderItems = null;
    XElement folderData = null;
    filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component };
    filter.Recursive = true;
    folderData = Client.GetListXml(folderUri, filter);
    folderItems = folderData != null ? folderData.Nodes() : null;
    return folderItems;
}
```

After fetching the Folder Components, then for each Folder item I call the following method to fetch the localized/locally created status.

```cs
public static bool GetComponentLocalizedStatus(string componentUri)
{
    ComponentData componentdata;
    bool status = false;
    componentdata = Client.Read(componentUri, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
    if (componentdata.BluePrintInfo.IsShared == false)
    {
       status = true;
    }
    else
       status = false;
    return status;
}
```

This approach is not efficient. Is there a way to fetch the locally created/ localized Components present in a Folder in single go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is; you can get the BluePrint state (`IsLocalized`/`IsShared`) included in the list data using `filter.BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Rick, they are quite useful. I have one query , is it possible to apply filter on "IsShared" property so that returned results are already filtered.

Comment: No, it isn't, but you can easily do your own post-filtering using XPath or LINQ.